# It's possible to pre save the knockoutjs view model to prevent refresh and data lost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, save

i have a MVC3 project with KnockoutJS and in my view.
The form that the user fills, has information already loaded from the server and the user is filling and selecting from this data so then, the user saves the data selected.
So... sometimes, the user, in the middle of the form, realize that some data is missing and it must cancel the form fill and edit the data that is missing and come back and do it again. So, my question is this... can i persist the view model in some way that the user can edit the missing data in other tab or window in the explorer and then refresh the form and dont lose the data?

I hope the explanation was clear.. my English is a little bit rusty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. If the data is on the same page, you could save the viewmodel data to another object, possibly using ko.toJSON. Then you can pull it back in later.

If you have to reload the page, you could save the viewmodel or the form's state in storage, using a library like amplify.js. http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/

pseudo code:

amplify.store('myData', myViewModel);